# How to write C string functions: strncpy , strncat , and strncmp

Tags: c, string, function

I'm solving this K&R exercise:

Write versions of the library functions strncpy , strncat , and strncmp , which operate on at most the first n characters of their argument strings. For example, strncpy(s,t,n) copies at most n characters of t to s . Full descriptions are in Appendix B.

So i was wandering if there's a site that contains source code for these string functions so i could check to see if i did something wrong.

These are the versions i wrote: i would appreciate if you would tell me if i have some bugs in the functions or something i should add/correct/improve!

```
int strncmp(char *s, char *t, int n)
{

     if(strlen(s) == strlen(t)) {

         while(*s == *t && *s && n) 
            n--, s++, t++;

         if(!n) 
             return 0; /* same length and same characters */
         else 
             return 1; /* same length, doesnt has the same characters */         
     }
     else
        return strlen(s) - strlen(t);
}

char *strncpy(char *s, char *t, int n)
{
     while(n-- && *s) {
        *s = *t;
        s++, t++;
     }

     if(strlen(t) < n)
        *s = '\0';

     return s;
}

char *strncat2(char *s, char *t, int n)
{
     while(*s)
       s++;

     while(n-- && *t) 
       *s = *t, s++, t++;

     *s = '\0';
     return s;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick look seems to reveal at least a couple of problems:

- In strncmp:  The strlen() call on the input is not valid.  They do not have to be null terminated.  Also, the return value should be <0, =0, >0 depending on the equality.
- strncpy:  I believe the library version pads the string with \0 to the end.

Comment: +1, and you're right: `strncpy()` pads the destination with `0`s at the end.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, there are plenty of open source implementations of `strncmp` and friends (e.g., strncmp [here](http://fxr.watson.org/fxr/source/libkern/strncmp.c?v=DFBSD)), but they won't necessarily help you that much.

Your `strncmp` for example just implements the wrong algorithm: it's **not** the case that a shorter string is always "less than" a longer one, e.g., `"z"` is **not** less than `"aa"` -- so you can't start by comparing the lengths only.

Your `strncpy` is checking `*s` where it should be checking `*t` instead, among other issues.

Seeing alternate open source implementations will not help much in diagnosing your bugs: peer review of your code, as you get by posting it to SO, probably helps more;-)

Answer (score 2):

Google code search is great for looking up implementations of standard functions :)
e.g. strncpy:

http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#XAzRy8oK4zA/libc/string/strncpy.c&q=strncpy&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc

Answer (score 0):

For solutions, see [CLC Wiki page](http://clc-wiki.net/wiki/K%26R2_solutions:Chapter_5:Exercise_5).

Now some comments about your code:

For `strncmp`:

```
if(strlen(s) == strlen(t)) {
```

You don't need this check.  `strlen()` traverses the string, so you are going to process the strings twice if the lengths are equal.  This can get expensive.  In general, low-level functions like these, which can be called a lot in any program should be efficient (although premature optimization is the root of all evil!).  Also, you're calling `strlen()` again for both the strings if the lengths aren't equal.  In addition to being expensive, it is wrong too, but we will come to that later.  About your `while` loop:

```
while(*s == *t && *s && n) 
    n--, s++, t++;
```

Why abuse the comma operator? I would simplify and write the above as (untested, after all, this is an exercise *you* are solving!):

```
while (*s && *t && *s == *t && n--) {
    s++;
    t++;
}
if (!n) return 0;
else return *s - *t;
```

Your return values are wrong.  `strncmp()` should return 0, less-than 0, or greater-than 0 depending upon whether the first `n` characters of the first string compare equal to, less than, or greater than (lexicographically) the second string.

Similarly, you should change your `strncpy()` and `strncat2()` functions.  I haven't looked at those two in detail, but since this is an exercise, you probably want to make the changes yourself anyway.

Comment: Lexicographicaly - does this means subtracting their ASCII values?

Comment: No, ASCII doesn't come in the picture here.  If a character set is such that `'a'` > `'b'`, then `strcmp("a", "b")` will return a number greater than 0, which might be surprising.  Lexicographic order is "dictionary order", but using platform-specific encoding for characters.  If you need to rely on the relative ordering of strings, `strcmp()` might not be the best way to do it (unless you're sure you're on "sane" systems!).

Comment: It is common to do "`return *s - *t;`" like I have for string comparison functions, but the standard only specifies the return values as 0, >0, and <0, so one could return any values satisfying that criterion.

Comment: Your return compares the wrong two values: "a1", "b1". On the way in *s = 'a' and *t = 'b'. They are not equal and the while breaks s and t are incremented and the return tests '1' - '1'.

Comment: Hmm. Thanks!  I fixed it.  As I had mentioned, the code above was untested. :-)

Answer (score 0):

For reference:

```
char* strncpy(char* s, const char* t, size_t n)
{
    char* ret = s; // need to return this
    while (n-- && *s++ = *t++)
         ;
    if (n) *s = 0;
    return ret;
}

// be lazy, there's no reason to write the copy part of strncpy and strncat twice.
char* strncat(char* s, const char* t, size_t n)
{
     char *ret = s;
     strncpy(s+strlen(s), t, n);
//
//   // if you don't want to call strlen, you can do this
//   while (*s++) ;
//   strncpy(s, t, n);
//
     return ret;
}

int strncmp(const char* s, const char* t, size_t n)
{
    while (n-- && *s == *t) {
          ++s;
          ++t;
    }
    if (n) return *s - *t;
    return 0;
}
```